# JMeter: Response Data is different from expected

Tags: jmeter, vaadin, jmeter-4.0

Im having a problem during performance test using JMeter. While recording the scripts, im using Data A as a sample. Then i use CSV Data Config which consist Data A too.

Once execution completed, I find out that transaction for Data A is passed while others failed to complete transaction.

**Expected Response**

```
for(;;);[{"syncId": 8, "clientId": 8, "changes" : [["change",{"pid":"0"},["0",{"id":"0","location":"http:\/\/***:8080\/aa_stg\/#!PatientDashboardView"},["css-injections",{},["css-string",{"id":332},".dashboard .v-panel-bcolor {border: 1px solid #fafafa !important; background-color: #fafafa !important;}"],["css-string",{"id":333},".p_margin {margin:5px;}"],["css-string",{"id":334},".dashboard .v-button-nobackgroundcust {padding: 0px !important;background: transparent;border: none !important;box-shadow: none !important;font-weight:bold;"]
```

**Actual Response:**

```
for(;;);[{"syncId": 8, "clientId": 8, "changes" : [["change",{"pid":"0"},["0",{"id":"0","location":"http:\/\/***:8080\/aa_stg\/#!BedManagementView"}]],["change",{"pid":"359"},["22",{"id":"359"}]],["change",{"pid":"46"},["22",{"id":"46"}]],["change",{"pid":"358"},["3",{"id":"358","iem":"LAZY","iet":400,"nvc":true}]],["change",{"pid":"35"},["23",{"id":"35","ormoh":false,"usehtml":true},["options",{},["moreItem",{"text":""}]],["items",{},["item",{"id":2,"style":"user-menu-caption","text":"<span class=\"noti-menu-badge\">0<\/span>","icon":"theme:\/\/img\/annoucement.png"},["item",{"id":3,"text":"Announcement","command":true}],["item",{"id":4,"text":"Update\/Create New Announcements","command":true}]
```

Thank you in advance for sharing your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Your response is clearly for different view that you recorded. It is really hard to say why though.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it show different view because only Data A getting the right response and go to next page while other data are stuck at the current page. I dont think it cause by sessionID